# java files are not adding properly in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL6L1.png)

in right side of java files might have some version issue, some times in this type of situation there is option of setup sdk but this time there was not option and even after changing version I'm stil getting this error (see java file icon right side).

Thank you.

Comment: make one class let say xyz.java in your client folder and check weather it shows error , check the package name in your files also

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using multiple sourceSets(full/limited) in your project.
If you run project with one source Set other source set files would be with read symbol.